# MySQL com o Supermetrics

Tags: mysql, python

Eu preciso criar um código em Python que salva os dados do Supermetrics no MySQL. Porém, eu sei muito pouco de Python.

Pesquisei algumas coisas e encontrei esse artigo do Supermetrics: https://supermetrics.com/blog/how-to-load-data-into-mysql

Mas não consegui decodificar para saber como faz. E o problema é que precisava fazer isso urgente.

Conseguem me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Queira editar sua postagem original conforme [as orientações já passadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/576266/70). Para evitar duplicidade de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta duplicata.